# What to call a fact/observation told by someone?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Examples:

> Speaker A: I thought he wanted to know about insects.
>
> Speaker B: But not [...] about them eating people!
>
> ---
>
> After he finished his [...] about seals.

I think using *fact* doesn't imply "talking". *Speech*, is more like something you'd do in public. And *story*, I think people usually associate them with fictitious accounts?

What's a better alternative?

Comment: In your first example, you don’t need any noun. “But not about them eating people!” works just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about [talk](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/talk) (the free dictionary):

```
    n

    18. a speech or lecture: a talk on ancient Rome.
    19. an exchange of ideas or thoughts: 
a business talk with a colleague.
    20. idle chatter, gossip, or rumour: 
there has been a lot of talk about you two.
    21. a subject of conversation; theme: 
our talk was of war.
    22. (Government, Politics & Diplomacy) (often plural)
 a conference, discussion, or negotiation: talks about a settlement.
    23. a specific manner of speaking: children's talk.
```

So we may say:

Speaker A: I thought he wanted to know about insects.

Speaker B: But not a **talk** about them eating people!

After he finished his **talk** about seals.

Answer (score 3):

Sojourner's solution *a talk* is perhaps the one I would choose but there are a few other options available.

Depending on how ironic, shocked or surprised "Speaker B" is, the following terms can be used:

> Speaker A: I thought he wanted to know about insects.
>
> Speaker B: But not **a spiel** about them eating people!
>
> After he finished his **spiel** about seals.

Merriam-Webster also defines **spiel** as [to talk volubly or extravagantly](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spiel)

If Speaker B is speaking sarcastically, or the OP wants to emphasize the depth and detail of Speaker's A description:

> Speaker A: I thought he wanted to know about insects.
>
> Speaker B: But not **a PowerPoint presentation** about them eating people!

A more serious alternative to PPP would be **demonstration**

> **demonstration**
>   [An act of showing that something exists or is true by giving proof or evidence](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/demonstration):
>    - *acts of faith are not capable of mathematical demonstration*

Answer (score 2):

Since you are talking about  specific facts/characteristics I think:

[description:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Description)  may fit in the context:

> - a statement or account that describes; representation in words

- But not a description about eating people.
- After he finished his description about seals.

Answer (score 2):

"Anecdote", perhaps?

"But not an anecdote about them eating people."

"After he finished his anecdote about seals..."

I use "anecdote" when describing someone in "story-telling mode".  An anecdote is "one-way" - from the speaker to the audience.  An anecdote can be told during a speech, in an informal group, or when talking informally with one other person:

"The speaker told a humorous anecdote about his lost luggage."
"Mark told me an interested anecdote about seeing whales while in Hawaii."

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anecdote

Answer (score 0):

But not a discourse about them eating people!

After he finished his spiel about seals.

But not an account of them eating people!

After he finished waxing poetic about seals.

But not a diatribe about them eating people!

After he finished his discourse about seals.

But not a chat about them eating people!

After he finished his A to Z about seals.

But not a contribution about them eating people!

After he finished giving his two cents about seals.

But not a monologue about them eating people!

After he finished giving his point of view about seals.

But not a story about them eating people!

After he finished his exposition about seals.

But not his ideas about them eating people!

After he finished developing his ideas about seals.

One more: megilla.